# PHP script continues execution even after exit()

Tags: php, performance, simplexml

So I have a relatively simple PHP script which

- Reads ~ 70 XML files from a remote rest service;
- Parses read XML files using SimpleXMLElement class (many new SimpleXMLElement() calls);
- Outputs to a file json encoded array which contains associative arrays where each array has a few attributes of interest from those XML files.

The problem with the script is that it finishes much later than it outputs the result to the file. I googled around but couldn't find anything that could cause such an issue. Below is simplified code which describes what my script does.

```
function parseFiles()
{
    $fileData = array();
    $parsedData = array();

    // read files using curl, output is an array of SimpleXMLElements
    readXMLFiles($fileData);

    // for each XML object create an assoc array which contains attributes
    // of interest, add it to $parsedData
    parseData($fileData, $parsedData);

    file_put_contents("test.txt", json_encode($parsedData));

    /*
    This is where the problem occures, the scipt outputs result to the file
    MUCH faster than it ends execution for example file is created with data
    in ~ 15 seconds but the script ends in 60 seconds 
    (so the exit() command took 45 seconds????)
    */
    exit();
}
```

Could this be caused by some kind of garbage collection once exit() is reached? Those XML objects are relatively large... Also I have tried to run the script on a wamp stack and on PHP, apache running on centos, the problem seems to be occuring on the centos machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by the [SimpleXML class](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php). No idea what was happening, but I came across [issue](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/issues/2854) where someone found that it was causing memory leaks, so I rewrote my code to work with [DOMDocument class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) which solve the issue.

Before the script would hang for ~ 2 minutes, after rewriting it completes in 13 seconds ;)